# jQuery image reloader function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do have a gif image load bar animation I do want it to reload when click Reload Image so that the animation will repeat.

```
//My HTML
<img src="http://i54.tinypic.com/2qdwtp0.gif" id="load-bar"/>
<a href="#" id="reloadImg">Reload Image</a>

//My js code

function imgRelaoder() {
//some stuff to reload image with id #load-bar
}    

$(function() {
    imgRelaoder();
    $("#reloadImg").click(imgRelaoder);
});
```

Comment: Why not just set the loop control on the GIF to infinite?

Comment: @mVChr I know it can be done infinite loop in GIF but I want to animate it once when page load and reload when click to repeat animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    var loadImg = document.getElementById('load-bar');

    $("#reloadImg").click(function() {
        loadImg.src = loadImg.src;
    }).click();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/27NV3/

Comment: that's is so simple and works GREAT Thanks Buddy!! I do a lot learn from here I'm too novice

Answer (score 0):

First, create an Image object and assign it a src property:

```
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = "path-to-your-loader.gif";
```

Then, in your function imgReloader:

```
    $("#load-bar").attr("src", image.src);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function imgRelaoder() {
    $("#load-bar").attr("src", 
        $("#load-bar").attr("src")
    );
}
```